# Azure in role cache exceptions when service scales

Tags: caching, azure

I am using Windows Azure SDK 2.2 and have created an Azure cloud service that uses an in-role cache.

I have 2 instances of the service running under normal conditions.

When the services scales (up to 3 instances, or back down to 2 instances), I get lots of DataCacheExceptions. These are often accompanied by Azure db connection failures from the process going in inside the cache. (If I don't find the entry I want in the cache, I get it from the db and put it into the cache. All standard stuff.)

I have implemented retry processes on the cache gets and puts, and use the ReliableSqlConnection object with a retry process for db connection using the Transient Fault Handling application block.
The retry process uses a fixed interval retrying every second for 5 tries.

The failures are typically;

Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException: ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later

Any idea why the scaling might cause these exceptions?
Should I try a less aggressive retry policy?

Any help appreciated.

I have also noticed that I am getting a high percentage (> 70%) cache miss rate and when the system is struggling, there is high cpu utilisation (> 80%).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I haven't been able to find out any reason for the errors I am seeing, but I have 'fixed' the problem, sort of!

When looking at the last few days processing stats, it is clear the high cpu usage corresponds with the cloud service having 'problems'. I have changed the service to use two medium instances instead of two small instances.

This seems to have solved the problem, and the service has been running quite happily, low cpu usage, low memory usage, no exceptions.

So, whilst still not discovering what the source of the problems were, I seem to have overcome them by providing a bigger environment for the service to run in.

--Late news!!! I noticed this morning that from about 06:30, the cpu usage started to climb, along with the time taken for the service to process as it should. Errors started appearing and I had to restart the service at 10:30 to get things back to 'normal'. Also, when restarting the service, the OnRoleRun process threw loads of DataCacheExceptions before it started running again, 45 minutes later.

Now all seems well again, and I will monitor for the next hours/days...

There seems to be no explanation for this, remote desktop to the instances show no exceptions in the event log, other logging is not showing application problems, so I am still stumped.

Comment: I have recently revamped the retry policy we were using for accessing the cache to provide an exponential back off instead of a fixed back off and this seems to work much better.